# print only if _DEBUG defined: c

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I want to print info only if `_DEBUG` is defined

```
#define DEBUG(y) y == true ? #define _DEBUG true  : #define _DEBUG false

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define Print(s)  printf(s); 
#endif
```

Getting Error:

```
error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this with pre-processor directives?

I intend to use it from my main as:

```
DEBUG(true);
Print("Inside main in debug mode");
```

Comment: From my understaning, the preprocessor statements are evaluated before compiling. So the the preprocess would evaluate the #Define statements before applying any of your logic. @JohnZwinck has the same approach that I would take.

Answer (score 5):

You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572872/changing-a-macro-at-runtime-in-c) redefine a MACRO at [run-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_%28program_lifecycle_phase%29). 
Neither you can have a [`#define` inside of another `#define`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314032/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-define-inside-of-another-define), like you try in the first line of your code.

You can do something like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define Print(s)  printf("%s", s)
#else
#define Print(s)  
#endif
```

And use it from your main as:

```
#define _DEBUG
Print("Inside main in debug mode");
#undef _DEBUG
Print("Inside main debug mode off");
```

If you really need to switch debug on and off at run-time, your can do something like this:

```
void PrintIf(BOOL dbg, char * msg)
{
   if (dbg)
   {
       printf("%s", msg)
   }
}
```

And use it like this

```
y = TRUE;
PrintIf(y,"Inside main in debug mode");
y = FALSE;
PrintIf(y,"Inside main debug mode off");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define Print(s) printf("%s", s)
#else
#define Print(s)
#endif
```

Then:

```
#define DEBUG
Print("Inside main in debug mode");
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, this won't work. The `Print` macro will get defined at the time the first block of code (`#ifdef DEBUG`) is parsed, so calling `#define DEBUG` or `#undef DEBUG` before using the `Print` macro will have no effect. That is, what `Print` does will already have been determined by the time it reaches the `#define DEBUG` line.

Comment: @Cookyt: You're right, `#define DEBUG` will need to come before the #include of whatever defines `Print()`.  Or else the check could be made into a "runtime" (but perhaps optimized out) one, without the preprocessor at all.

Answer (score 1):

> I intend to use it from my main as:
>
> ```
> DEBUG(y);
> Print("Inside main in debug mode");
> ```

Sorry, but `ifdef` are compile time (not run-time). You could use a global bool and runtime checking to enable and disable debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create preprocessor statements with macros as you are trying to do; it doesn't work and isn't allowed.  For conditional printing, see [C `#define` macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898).

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs here:

```
#define DEBUG(y) y == true ? #define _DEBUG true  : #define _DEBUG false
```

When introducing `#defines`, the definition `#` occurs at the beginning of the line, not later (although) preprocessors generally allow one or two line indents.) You need to rewrite your `#define` eliminating the ternary operator simply as:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define Print(s)  printf(s); 
#endif
```

While you may extend you defines with macros, you often introduce additional errors. It is generally better to stick to wrapping your _DEBUG code simply in `#ifdef` statements:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    fprintf (stderr, "your error messages\n");  // using standard printf/fprintf instead of macros
    ...
#endif  /* _DEBUG */
```

Answer (score 1):

Macros are substituted at preprocessing stage and

```
#define DEBUG(y) y == true ? #define _DEBUG true  : #define _DEBUG false
```

this statement will be evaluated at compile time.

Conditional operator (ternary operator) are evaluated at compile time. So you are getting this error and # operator must always be used at the beginning of the statement that is the second mistake you are doing.

You can better use it this way

```
#define DEBUG
printf ("true");
#else
printf ("false");
```

You can also define this macro dynamically by using the gcc option -D

```
gcc -D DEBUG filename.c -o outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line is incorrect:

```
#define DEBUG(y) y == true ? #define _DEBUG true  : #define _DEBUG false
```

You cannot use `#define` inside preprocessor directive (like another `#define`)

And it does not make sense, since [preprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) happens before the real compilation (so before run time, when your `y` has some value). Read the [`cpp` preprocessor documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). Recall that sometimes the preprocessor is even a different program (`/lib/cpp`) but is today the first phase of most C compilers.

You could ask for the preprocessed form of your source code (e.g. with `gcc -C -E source.c > source.i` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and look at that form with a pager (`less source.i`) or your editor.